# Why does semget() cause an EACCES error when *creating* a semaphore?

Tags: c++, unix, permissions, ipc, semaphore

I have to make a semaphore array for a C++ project. I'm not calling `semget()` from `main()`; I've got a separate method to make it easier, albeit a method in `main.cpp`. When my program reaches `semget(semkey,nsems,0666|IPC_CREAT)`, it returns -1 with an EACCES errno, which apparently means "A semaphore identifier exists for `key`, but operation permission as specified by the low-order 9 bits of `semflg` would not be granted."

I've gone over and over my code with GDB. All three parameters for `semget()` look right, and this is the first point at which the program call `semget()`, so the semaphore doesn't exist already; I even ran `ipcs -s` to make sure. I've got `#include <sys/sem.h>` at the top of `main.cpp`.

What's going on here? I've already created and attached a shared memory segment, could that have something to do with it? I can't see how.

Comment: Does it work correctly the first time after a reboot?

Comment: I haven't tried. That affects it, then? Why?

Comment: Well, cleaning up with `ipcs` should have done the trick, but to be sure, rebooting the system will surely clean up any leftover shared resources (semaphores, shared memory, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

From the manual :

```
 EACCES A semaphore set exists for key, but the calling process does not have permission to 
        access the set, and does not have the CAP_IPC_OWNER capability.
```

As a reminder, since semaphore are system object, it is deleted only when a system call is explicitly issued for this. (`semctl` with `IPC_RMID`, or `ipcrm` term command).
In addition, the `semkey` has to be unique (retrieve from a `ftok()` function for example), or it is possible that another program created it before your very first call to `semget`. Since, it would exist, you would catch the so-called `EACCES` error, cause not all programs uses 0666 permission on semaphore like you do.

Reboot flushes the shared objects pool (semaphore, shared memory segments, message queue) as would :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ipcs -s | cut -f 2 -d ' '`
do
   ipcrm -s $i
done

for i in `ipcs -m | cut -f 2 -d ' '`
do
   ipcrm -m $i
done

for i in `ipcs -q | cut -f 2 -d ' '`
do
   ipcrm -q $i
done
```